# Random forest with bounded dependent variable

Tags: random-forest

if my depedent variable is bounded, a fraction between [0-1], can I work with random forest and garantee that the model won't give me results out of my bound?

Comment: What does the variable you want to predict represent?

Comment: it represents the percentage of people who memorize a TV ad. so it is from 0%  to 100%

Comment: As the final fit of a random forrest for regression is the mean of the leaves in the same group, you should never get predictions out of ound.